# Can you have a bare block in C?

Tags: c

I know that in C# and JavaScript, the following is perfectly valid:

```
{
  var foo;
}
```

Is having a bare block valid in C too?

i.e. is this valid C?

```
{
  int foo;
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this won't compile. So it's *no* valid C!

Comment: In C? Yes, I know. It is valid C# and JavaScript though, no? I am asking specifically about having a bare block (ignoring the syntax for variable declaration).

Comment: Err ... if you know this, why are you asking, though? :-S

Comment: It behaves differently in C and C# than in Javascript. In JS, the variable `foo` can be used anywhere in the function, even outside the block where it was declared with `var`.

Comment: Even if you'd changed `var` to `int` or whatever, it won't compile.

Comment: @alk Where does the question state that this is a `program`? It's a perfectly valid `statement`.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff: Fair enough ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this valid in C too?

Yes, it is and it is called a *compound statement*.

From the C11 Standard:

```
6.8.2 Compound statement
Syntax
1 compound-statement:
    { block-item-listopt }
block-item-list:
    block-item
    block-item-list block-item
block-item:
    declaration
    statement
```

A compound-statement is itself a *statement* in C.

For example this block is a valid block:

```
{
    {
        {
            printf("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Even this one is valid:

```
{{{}}}
```

`{}` is  an empty compound statement.

Comment: Can you expand on the reason for the name? What is compounded?

Comment: Because it's a statement that can be made of multiple statements.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's totally fine!

As an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

{   
    int i = 5;  //If you declare i outside you can use both print statements
    printf("%d", i);
}


//printf("%d", i);  Note that i is out of scope here

    return 0;

}
```